# Scraping a website whose url doesn't change

Tags: java, dom, web-scraping, jsoup

I am currently scraping this website.

http://www.davidsassoonlibrary.com/index.php?action=book_details

But no matter which book I search, the URL remains the same.
I am completely new to web scraping.
I have scraped 2 pages using Jsoup and trying to do the same for this website too.

Anyone has any Ideas. Please explain in as much detail as possible.
Thankyou

Comment: I'm getting dns lookup failed. Perhaps they don't want you to scrape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use post request to scrape the web page with some parameters search and title, try the code below:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.davidsassoonlibrary.com/index.php?action=book_details")
  .data("search", "search")
  .data("title", "Test Cricket Lists")
  //fields which are being passed in post request.
  .userAgent("Mozilla")
  .post();
   System.out.println(doc); // will print html source
```

This is the result on console:

[image: Code and console]

You can use firebug to dermine which URL is Called, method GET or POS and parameters.

[image: Post URL and parameters]

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thank you so much but what does .userAgent do? I got your entire code except it.

Comment: In many example you'll find user agent set to Mozilla, the site can retun different html based on your request user-agent(mobile/non mobile version of site)